# Hamburger menu dropdown on the right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to position the hamburger menu on the right when I click on it, but I'm not managing to adjust the CSS for that.

I have this `HTML` code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Ad this `CSS`:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

How to adjust this CSS so that the hamburger menu is on the right when clicking on it? The padding of the boxes must be appropriate to the size of the words inside it. Like this:

[image]

**It's okay if it overwrites the space under it.**

I need a solution that uses this `CSS` code, only. See more [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/120604).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change collapse.in selector to

```
.collapse.in{
    display:block !important;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but the background-color dissapear and the entire navbar appears before the menu is positioned on the right. How adjust this? Thanks.

Comment: add background: inherit!important; and width: auto

Comment: The effect of navbar doesn't dissapear. It appears in full before the menu is positioned on the right.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/120604 , thats what i could come up in that hour.. I would suggest you to assign your colorings to the .navbar-collapse selector, like I have assigned background-color to it. Hope it helps a bit